# org-latex-preview fails when \usepackage{fontspec} used

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

To write in different language, I'm exploring different `LaTeX` engine mainly `XeLaTex`.

```org
#+LATEX_COMPILER: xelatex
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{fontspec}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setmainfont{CMU Serif}

* This is a test, (энэ бол тест)
\begin{equation}
a + b + c +d + e + f + g + h
\end{equation}
```

- Above org-file, `M-x org-latex-export-to-pdf` produces `pdf` file without any issue.
- But, (when I try to preview each equation) `M-x org-latex-preview` gives following error.

```
org-compile-file: File "/tmp/orgtexRzIPhL.dvi" wasn’t produced.  Please adjust ‘dvipng’ part of ‘org-preview-latex-process-alist’.
```

**Question**:
What am I doing wrong?, How can I fix this?

---

**Additional info**:
I played around little bit, and found that `M-x org-latex-preview` fails only when `\usepackage{fontspec}` exist.

The value of `org-preview-latex-process-alist` (As NickD suggested to include):

```elisp
Value:
((dvipng :programs
         ("latex" "dvipng")
         :description "dvi > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvipng." :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
         (1.0 . 1.0)
         :latex-compiler
         ("latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
         :image-converter
         ("dvipng -D %D -T tight -o %O %f")
         :transparent-image-converter
         ("dvipng -D %D -T tight -bg Transparent -o %O %f"))
 (dvisvgm :programs
          ("latex" "dvisvgm")
          :description "dvi > svg" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvisvgm." :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "svg" :image-size-adjust
          (1.7 . 1.5)
          :latex-compiler
          ("latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
          :image-converter
          ("dvisvgm %f --no-fonts --exact-bbox --scale=%S --output=%O"))
 (imagemagick :programs
              ("latex" "convert")
              :description "pdf > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and imagemagick." :image-input-type "pdf" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
              (1.0 . 1.0)
              :latex-compiler
              ("pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
              :image-converter
              ("convert -density %D -trim -antialias %f -quality 100 %O")))
```

Comment: I deleted the `preview-latex` tag: `preview-latex` is part of `auctex` and has nothing to do with `org-latex-preview` (although it probably should, but that's fodder for another conversation...)

Comment: @NickD, Thanks, I'll try to remember next time.

Comment: What is the value of `org-preview-latex-process-alist`? Please add it to the question. You probably need to adjust the `dvipng` part of it to use `xelatex` instead of whatever it is using currently. Although `dvipng` would then be a misnomer...

Comment: I don't know if `xelatex` can produce `dvi` output. You might be better off modifying the `imagemagick` method which goes through `pdf` rather than `dvi` and do `(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'imagemagick)` to use that method instead of `dvipng`.

Comment: @NickD, Thanks for the tip. After `(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'imagemagick)`, it outputs: `org-compile-file: File "/tmp/orgtexJpyLfC.pdf" wasn’t produced.  Please adjust ‘imagemagick’ part of ‘org-preview-latex-process-alist’.`. I'm not sure how to debug further

Comment: Change the `:latex-compiler` field of the `imagemagick` section from `pdflatex` to `xelatex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the modifications to add to your init file:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'org
  (setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'imagemagick)
  (setf (plist-get (cdr (assq 'imagemagick org-preview-latex-process-alist)) :latex-compiler)
        '("xelatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")))
```

When `org` is loaded, then the `org-preview-latex-default-process` will be set to `imagemagick`, which takes the fragment, compiles it with LaTeX to produce a PDF and then calls `convert` to convert the PDF to a PNG. The assumption is that you have installed `imagemagick` of course, otherwise the `convert` step will fail.

It also changes the LaTeX compiler of the `imagemagick` section from the default `pdflatex` to `xelatex`.

You could also use `customize` on these two variables: it would probably be easier, particularly for changing the LaTeX compiler entry.

Try it and see if it works.